# How to check that message exists with catkin for conditional compilation (sensor_msgs/BatteryState)

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i want to add support for new message but i need some "how to" on detecting available messages with catkin.

I'm thinking to use cmake execute_process() for that. Some thing like that:

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} -c "from sensor_msgs.msg import BatteryState"
    RESULT_VARIABLE BATTERY_STATE_RESULT
)
```

But maybe catkin already has some macro for that task?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223769/how-to-check-that-message-exists-with-catkin-for-conditional-compilation-(sensor_msgs/batterystate)/) by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 404 on 2016-01-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2016-01-10**:
An alternative way would be to use something like `rosmsg show sensor_msgs/BatteryState`. Also there seems to be generated variables of the form `<package_name>_MESSAGE_FILES` which are the lists of paths. However, to get it you probably have to `find_package` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Within CMake you can access the list of message/service files of a package since every message package exports these information in via its CMake extras file. After calling:

```
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
```

or

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS std_msgs)
```

the list of message files is available in the CMake variable:

```
std_msgs_MESSAGE_FILES
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2016-01-11**:
Looks like i need that code:

```
list(FIND sensor_msgs_MESSAGE_FILES "msg/BatteryState.msg" BATTERY_STATE_MSG_IDX)
if(${BATTERY_STATE_MSG_IDX} >= 0)
endif()
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is tricky, because there are not a lot of good ways to do it.

Old versions of `rosmsg show` does not return an error code if the message does not exist, so that probably isn't the best choice.

The python messages aren't generated until the build step, so they may not exist at configure time, which means that a python script which tries to import messages will always fail the first time, even if the package contains the messages you're looking for.

I think the best way to do this would be to check which version of sensor_msgs you're building against from cmake, and use that as the conditional in your build. You can do this with the `VERSION_GREATER` or `VERSION_LESS` comparisons:

```
# cmake
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    sensor_msgs 
    # etc
)

if( ${sensor_msgs_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 2.42.3 ) # substitute the version you care about
    message("sensor_msgs too old; won't build foo")
else()
    # build cool new things
endif()
```

(This SHOULD work; but I haven't tested it. May need a little tweaking)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1